# How to declare an optional field in Google Pub/Sub Topic Schema?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, avro, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to create a Pub/Sub Schema Topic on AVRO respecting the indications on the documentation with `"default" : null` indication.
I declared my optional field this way :

```
{
   "name": "myField",
   "type": ["null","string"],
   "default": null
}
```

The error I get :

```
Incorrect token in the stream. Expected: Object start, found String
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: Hi @Snowfire, Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Yes, I decided to let it go and go with schemaless topic.

Comment: Hi @Snowfire, Can you provide your resolution steps as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you would like, but I would probably try something like this:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "SomeName",
  "fields": [
    {
        "name": "myField",
        "type": ["string", "null"]
    }
  ]
}
```

as defined in [Apache Avro specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/) and described in [PubSub Schema creation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/schemas#schema_types)

Comment: I doesn't work either that way :/

Comment: So you tried to create a topic with a schema and it was not created. Can you try to follow examples of topic creation from the documentation, please?

Answer (score -1):

@Snowfire, you have mentioned in the comment that you choose to continue with schema-less topic.

You can follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/schemas) to create Pub/Sub Schema.

To create a schema of Avro type you can try this:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "testname",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "testId",
      "type": ["null", "int"],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I tested below message against the schema and it works.

```
{
  "testname": {
    "string": "Jack"
  },
  "testId": {
    "int": 101
  }
}
```

Comment: It validates the message but if you have a BQ subscriptions pipeline, it doesn't work, see this issue for reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242757468